# Capture ESCAPE key using termios under OSX

Tags: c, macos, terminal, xterm, termios

I am  trying to capture ESC key (ASCII 27) on a OSX terminal or `xterm` using kbhit to distinguish a real Escape from Arrow keys:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static struct termios newt;
static struct termios oldt;

static void kb_fini(void)
{
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
}

void kb_init(void)
{
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= (tcflag_t)~(ICANON | ECHO | ISIG);
    newt.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    newt.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    atexit(kb_fini);
}

static int kb_hit(void)
{
    int c = 0;

    newt.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    c = getc(stdin);
    newt.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    if (c != -1) {
        ungetc(c, stdin);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int c;

    kb_init();
    printf("Press ESC several times\n");
    while (1) {
        c = getchar();
        if ((c == 27) && (kb_hit() == 0)) {
            printf("You pressed ESC\n");    
        } else
        if (c == '\n') {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it only works the first time, the second time I press the escape key, the terminal doesn't admit more data. It doesn't freeze completely, as the prompt keeps blinking, but pressing more keys doesn't change anything.

Comment: Works for me on Linux. Have you tried to run it under a debugger?

Comment: Thank you @n.m., yes, it works also for me on Debian, Mavericks comes without gdb nor valgrind, is not my laptop and I can not install it :(

Comment: I hear restoring VMIN to 1 doesn't always work on OSX. https://bitbucket.org/techtonik/python-pager/issues/5/read-doesnt-block-on-mac-os-x. No idea how to cope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulating `VTIME` and `VMIN` like that would be useful if you were reading the standard input directly using `read`.  However, you are reading it via the C stream input *stdin*, which means that you are relying on a particular behavior for *that*, rather than the low-level termios feature.

The program loops because `getchar` has decided it has detected an end-of-file condition, and continues to return -1, never returning to `kb_hit`.  You can amend that by calling

```
clearerr(stdin);
```

after the call to `getchar` (since it resets the end-of-file condition), though relying upon any particular behavior or interaction between stream and low-level I/O is nonportable.

For instance, the Linux manual pages for [getchar](http://www.whoopis.com/howtos/man.php?query=getchar&type=2&section=3) and [gets](http://t2.hhg.to/man/htmlman3/gets.3.html) advise

> It is not advisable to mix calls to input functions from the stdio library with low-level calls to **`read(2)`** for the file descriptor associated with the input stream; the results will be undefined and very probably not what you want.

For reference:

- [stdio(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/stdio.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/stdio)
- [clearerr(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/clearerr.3.html)
- [read(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/read.2.html)

Comment: Thank you Thomas, you mean it is preferable to use `read` instead of `getchar`? (regardless of fault)

Comment: yes: without delving into the source-code for OSX's `getchar`, I could not tell exactly *why* it set the `EOF` condition.  These internal details are not well-standardized (and can differ).  But using `read`, you can make the prorgram much more predictable and portable.

Comment: Does `read` puts `stdout` in line buffered mode?, I have to `fflush(stdout);` when I use `read` instead of `getchar()`

Comment: `read` does not affect `stdout`.  Your program may mix other calls such as `write` and `printf` which could be relevant.

Comment: Thank you again Thomas, sorry but I don't get you, before switching from `getchar` to `read`,  I was able to `printf("something");` without a trailing newline or a call to `fflush(stdout);`. Something has changed.

Comment: Perhaps you could add your revised program to the current question (or start a new question).

Comment: Yes, I ask a new question.